# Prevent useEffect from firing twice with useReducer when using StrictMode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-reducer

I'm using React's Strict mode, and I'm having a `useEffect` that is causing me some headaches. Part of React's Strict mode is that those things can fire twice, so I'm writing code to protect myself from that.

However I seem to be missing something when using `useReducer`. By using `useState` I'm able to update the state so that `useEffect` becomes idempotent.

With `useReducer` I dispatch an action which only seems to be executed AFTER `useEffect` has rendered twice, effectively nullifying my idempotency.

`useState` example (pardon the React setup cruft, StackOverflow doesn't support React 18 natively):

```js
const { StrictMode, useState, useEffect } = React;

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <WithUseState />
  </StrictMode>
);

function WithUseState() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (counter === 0) {
      setCounter(counter + 1);
    }
  }, [counter]);

  return <React.Fragment>{counter}</React.Fragment>;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

`useReducer` example, where the order seems to be: `useEffect`, `useEffect`, resolve `dispatch`, resolve `dispatch`:

```js
const { StrictMode, useEffect, useReducer } = React;

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <WithUseReducer />
  </StrictMode>
);

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
case "increment":
  return { ...state, counter: state.counter + 1 };
default:
  throw new Error();
  }
}

function WithUseReducer() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, { counter: 0 });

  useEffect(() => {
if (state.counter === 0) {
  dispatch({ type: "increment" });
}
  });

  return <React.Fragment>{state.counter}</React.Fragment>;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: This doesn't happen with the production build of react, i.e. the reducer will not run twice.

Comment: Check out this blog-post where they bring up the third parameter for `useReducer` (init function). https://blog.logrocket.com/react-usereducer-hook-ultimate-guide/ should allow you to get the same result in dev and production environments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the production build of React. `useEffect` running twice was added in React 18: https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#ensuring-reusable-state

```js
const { StrictMode, useEffect, useReducer } = React;

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <WithUseReducer />
  </StrictMode>
);

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
case "increment":
  return { ...state, counter: state.counter + 1 };
default:
  throw new Error();
  }
}

function WithUseReducer() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, { counter: 0 });

  useEffect(() => {
if (state.counter === 0) {
  dispatch({ type: "increment" });
}
  });

  return <React.Fragment>{state.counter}</React.Fragment>;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In **react 18**, `useEffect` will be  called twice in `Strict Mode` This happens only in development mode not in production mode .  to prevent this behavior in development mode  you can use a custom hook instead of `useEffect` .

```
export const useEffectOnce = (effect) => {
  const destroyFunc = useRef();
  const effectCalled = useRef(false);
  const renderAfterCalled = useRef(false);
  const [val, setVal] = useState(0);

  if (effectCalled.current) {
    renderAfterCalled.current = true;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // only execute the effect first time around
    if (!effectCalled.current) {
      destroyFunc.current = effect();
      effectCalled.current = true;
    }

    // this forces one render after the effect is run
    setVal((val) => val + 1);

    return () => {
      // if the comp didn't render since the useEffect was called,
      // we know it's the dummy React cycle
      if (!renderAfterCalled.current) {
        return;
      }
      if (destroyFunc.current) {
        destroyFunc.current();
      }
    };
  }, []);
};
```

check this  [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/combobox-material-demo-forked-knzpl4?file=/demo.js) (it is using you example but firing just once )

Answer (score 0):

You could add a cleanup function to your useEffect that resets the state when unmounted (because React 18 mounts, then unmounts, then mounts again).

(The isMounted state is only needed if state should be persistent between views/different component renders).

```js
const { StrictMode, useEffect, useReducer } = React;

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <WithUseReducer />
  </StrictMode>
);

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "increment":
      return { ...state, counter: state.counter + 1 };
    case "mount-reset":
      if (!state.isMounted)
        return { ...state, counter: 0, isMounted: true };
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

function WithUseReducer() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, { counter: 0 });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (state.counter === 0) {
      dispatch({ type: "increment" });
    }
    return () => dispatch({ type: "mount-reset" });
  }, []);

  return <React.Fragment>{state.counter}</React.Fragment>;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

See these for further explanations:

[Bug: useEffect runs twice on component mount (StrictMode, NODE_ENV=development)](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24502)

[How to handle data fetching happening twice?](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#how-to-handle-the-effect-firing-twice-in-development)